# OpenCV: Fill Mat in while loop?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I'm using OpenCV, and I'm trying to fill a Mat of size

`cv::Mat Mat = cv::Mat(DEPTH_HEIGHT, DEPTH_WIDTH, CV_16U);`

and fill it with the `depth` value in this while loop:

```
        while (curr < dataEnd) {
        // Get depth in millimeters
        USHORT depth = NuiDepthPixelToDepth(*curr++);
        cv::Mat Mat++ = depth;
        }
```

Is there some way to iterate into the Mat such that each depth value is stored in a HeightxWidth Mat index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (i=0;i<mat.rows;i++)
{
 uint16_t* ptr = mat.ptr<uint16_t>(i);
 for (j=0;j<mat.cols;j++)
 {
   *ptr++ = value for pixel (i,j)
 }     
}
```

Note you should use ptr(row#) because the start of each row of pixels may be aligned to an address boundary.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `uint16_t* ptr = mat.ptr<uint16_t>(i);`?

Comment: Yep, this did the trick. @B... was right, it needed the `mat.ptr<uint16_t>(i)` in there (I used ushort, but whatever). Cheers!

Comment: @B yes, or cast the returned point to ushort*. Since the row is boundary aligned it doesn't matter